# Kivy : Black screen when i added function on main loop

Tags: python, kivy

```
def Lnlau(self): #LNLAU = Load_Nodeid_List_And_Update
    FRM = open('NodeidList.txt', 'r') #FileReadMode

    while True:
    for i, l in enumerate(FRM):
        if (i)%2 == 1: #1 , 3 ,5 ,7...
            l_new = l.rstrip('\n')
            FSM = l_new

            linecontents = BusInfo_Update()
            linecontents.Update(FSM) #BusInfo_Update().Update(FSM) eg) FSM = 'ICB23221.txt' 
        else:
            pass
```

i want start above this function when i start application.
so i added this function to `class Loading_Screen(Screen)`
and use `Clock.schedule_once(self.Lnlau, 0)` but all i could get on the screen was a black screen. no errors. if i get rid of this function on `main.py`, no problems. What should i do? make new class to use this function?

main.py

```
__version__ = "1.0"
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import kivy
import os
kivy.require('1.10.0')
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.animation import Animation
from kivy.clock import Clock
#from kivy.config import Config #windows size fixed
#Config.set('graphics', 'resizable', 0)
from kivy.core.window import Window 
Window.size = (1080, 1920) 
##########FOR BUS INFORMATION UPDATE#############
from urllib import urlencode, quote_plus
from urllib2 import Request as RQ
from urllib2 import urlopen as UO
import urllib
import xml.etree.ElementTree as etree
import os
import datetime

class Loading_Screen(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Loading_Screen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        Clock.schedule_once(self.callNext, 2) 

    def callNext(self,dt): 
        self.manager.current = 'Before_First_Screen'

class Load_BusInfo():
    pass

class Before_First_Screen(Screen):
    pass

class First_Screen(Screen):
    pass

class Test_Screen(Screen):
    pass

###################destination_station_name#####################

class DTN_TECHNOPARK(Screen): 
    pass

class DTN_BITZONE(Screen): 
    pass

class DTN_INUSTATION(Screen): 
    pass

class Bus_Information(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Bus_Information, self).__init__(**kwargs)
    #oo = os.path.join('/data/data/org.test.tubuc/files/app/station/', 'ICB164000039.txt')
    oo = os.path.join('/root/hi/station/', 'ICB164000039.txt')
        with open(oo) as businfo:
            Businfo= [] 
            nolinenum=businfo.readline()
            while nolinenum!='': 
                Businfo.append(nolinenum)
                leftstations = (businfo.readline().rstrip('\n') + ' stations'.rstrip('\n'))
                lefttime = (businfo.readline().rstrip('\n') + ' seconds'.rstrip('\n'))
                nolinenum = businfo.readline().rstrip('\n')
                Businfo.append(leftstations)
                Businfo.append(lefttime)
            self.businfolist = Businfo
            self.lenbil = int(len(Businfo))
            self.numberoflist = int(len(Businfo)/3)

class ScreenManagement(ScreenManager):
    pass

presentation = Builder.load_file("main.kv")

class TubucApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return presentation


TubucApp().run()
```

main.kv

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
#:import NoTransition kivy.uix.screenmanager.NoTransition
#:import Label kivy.uix.button.Label

ScreenManagement:
    transition: NoTransition()
    Loading_Screen:
    Before_First_Screen:
    First_Screen:
    Test_Screen:
    DTN_TECHNOPARK:
    DTN_BITZONE:
    DTN_INUSTATION:
    Bus_Information:

<Loading_Screen>:
    name: 'Loading_Screen'
    canvas:
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
            source: 'image/Loading_Screen.png'

<Before_First_Screen>:
    name: 'Before_First_Screen'
    Button:
        canvas:
            Rectangle:
                pos: self.pos
                size: self.size
                source: 'image/BBG2.png'
        on_release:
            app.root.current = 'First_Screen'

<First_Screen>:
    name: 'First_Screen'

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'horizontal'
        spacing: 50 # spacing between button
        padding: [50, 50, 50, 50]
        canvas:
            Rectangle:
                pos: self.pos
                size: self.size 
                source: 'image/background.png' #backgroundimage
        Button:
            id: dongmak
            width: 40
            pos_hint: {'x' : 0, 'y':.45}
            size_hint: [.6,.1]
            background_normal:'image/2.png'
            background_down:'image/after.png'
            border: (0,0,0,0)
            on_release: app.root.current = 'Bus_Information'
        Button:
            id: campustown
            color: 100,100,100,100 #text_color
            width: 40
            pos_hint: {'x' : 0, 'y':.45}
            size_hint: [.6,.1]
            background_normal:'image/3.png'
            background_down:'image/after.png'
            border: (0,0,0,0)
            on_release: app.root.current = 'DTN_BITZONE'
        Button:
            id: technopark
            color: 100,100,100,100 #text_color
            pos_hint: {'x' : 0, 'y':.45}
            size_hint: [.6,.1]
            background_normal:'image/4.png'
            background_down:'image/after.png'
            border: (0,0,0,0)
            on_release: app.root.current = 'DTN_INUSTATION'
        Button:
            id: bitzone
            width: 40
            pos_hint: {'x' : 0, 'y':.45}
            size_hint: [.6,.1]
            background_normal:'image/5.png'
            background_down:'image/after.png'
            border: (0,0,0,0)   
        Button:
            id: inustation
            width: 40
            pos_hint: {'x' : 0, 'y':.45}
            size_hint: [.6,.1]
            background_normal:'image/1.png'
            background_down:'image/after.png'
            border: (0,0,0,0)
            #font_size: 15
            #text: 'inustation'
<Test_Screen>:
    name: 'Test_Screen'

    Button:
        on_release: app.root.current = 'First_Screen'
        text: 'back to the home screen'
        font_size: 50

############destionation_station_name################
<DTN_TECHNOPARK>:
    name: 'DTN_TECHNOPARK'

    Button:
        on_release: app.root.current = 'First_Screen'
        text: 'destionation >> technopark'
        font_size: 50

<DTN_BITZONE>:
    name: 'DTN_BITZONE'

    Button:
        on_release: app.root.current = 'First_Screen'
        text: 'destionation >> bitzone'
        font_size: 50

<DTN_INUSTATION>:
    name: 'DTN_INUSTATION'

    Button:
        on_release: app.root.current = 'First_Screen'
        text: 'destionation >> inustation'
        font_size: 50
######################################################
<Bus_Information>:
    name: 'Bus_Information'
    canvas:
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size 
            source: 'image/BBG.png' #backgroundimage

    #for sero in range(root.numberoflist):
    #   for garo in range(3):


    GridLayout:
        cols: 3
        rows: root.numberoflist
        spacing: 0
        padding: [0,100]
        on_parent:
            for i in range(root.lenbil): txt = root.businfolist[i]; self.add_widget(Label(text = txt, text_size=(cm(2), cm(2)), 
            pos=self.pos, id=txt))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Problem: Endless While Loop in Kivy App

When you run your Kivy App which contains `While True:` in `Lnlau(self)` function,  the program will never exit your loop, preventing Kivy from doing all of the other things that need doing. As a result, all you’ll see is a **black window** which you won’t be able to interact with.

## Solution

Use [Clock.schedule_interval()](https://kivy.org/docs/guide/events.html#scheduling-a-repetitive-event) or [Clock.create_trigger()](https://kivy.org/docs/guide/events.html#trigger-events) functions to “schedule” your `Lnlau()` function to be called repeatedly.

Comment: Hi @ikolim Thanks for the solution. i faced another problem. What i want is `Lulau()` function to be called once. so i used `Clock.schedule_once(Lnlau, 10)` in front of whole line. But, the problem is Kivy App stops on the current screen after 10secs(after `Lnlau()` called)